# Ropemacs default refactoring

Tags: python, refactoring

I'm performing a large python refactor, and one component of that is renaming many variables from camelCase to snake_case. I'd like to hook a camel-to-snake conversion function (which I already have) into the default values of `rope-refactor`.

When I inspect `rope-refactor`, I get the following information.

```
rope-rename is an interactive Lisp function.

(rope-rename &rest ARGUMENTS)

It interfaces to a Python function.
```

Rope interfaces with Emacs through Pymacs. What would be the recommended way of achieving these defaults? Should I make the change in Rope's python modules, or is there an elegant way of setting the default arguments on the elisp side? I'd prefer the latter.

Comment: First, you need to determine what arguments `rope-rename` requires. (Can you view it's definition? We should be able to tell from the `(interactive)` spec). After that, making some arguments default is child's play.